# Is It Possible to Use Any Child React Element inside RouterProvider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've successfully created several route configurations using React Router 6, and they are working as expected. Additionally, I've developed an `AxiosInterceptor` component to handle HTTP requests and responses. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to use the `AxiosInterceptor` component within my application because it relies on the `useNavigate` hook, requiring it to be placed inside the `BrowserRouter`.

Here's an example of my route configurations

**AuthRoute.tsx**

```
import { Navigate, RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Navigate to="/sign-in" />
    },
    {
        path: 'sign-in',
        async lazy() {
            const { SignIn } = await import('@/modules/auth');
            return { Component: SignIn };
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'forget-password',
        async lazy() {
            const { ForgetPassword } = await import('@/modules/auth');
            return { Component: ForgetPassword };
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'reset-password',
        async lazy() {
            const { ResetPassword } = await import('@/modules/auth');
            return { Component: ResetPassword };
        }
    }
];

export default AuthRoutes;
```

**AppRoutes.tsx**

```
const AppRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        element: <AuthLayout />,
        children: [...AuthRoutes]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        element: <AdminLayout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                children: DashboardRoutes
            }
        ]
    }
];

export default AppRoutes;
```

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <AuthContextProvider>
                {/* <AxiosInterceptor> */}
                <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(AppRoutes)} />

                {/* </AxiosInterceptor> */}
            </AuthContextProvider>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```